# Getting 500 error when access product page magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, layout

When I add a product to muy category this what I found as results 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let turn on debug mode in Magento. Uncomment/add this code into `app/bootstrap.php`

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Reload the product page to see the error message.

Comment: ok i will do that immediately

Comment: thanks  i can now see the error

Comment: I used a plugin to show custom attribute instead of name product but i can't get the value now

Comment: If you're trying to show the attribute in product detail page, you should load the product model again then get the attribute. Because the model used in detail page is different to the original product model. Use `$product->getData();` to check what attributes are contained in it.

Comment: public function afterGetName(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
    {

        $title = $subject->getResource()->getAttribute('famille_pdt')->setStoreId(1)->getFrontend()->getValue($subject) ."\t".
            $subject->getResource()->getAttribute('the_business_name_pdt')->setStoreId(1)->getFrontend()->getValue($subject);
        var_dump($title);

        return nl2br($title);


    }

Comment: i tried with a plugin  and the function after getName

Comment: the problem is with function setStoreIdit's said Call to a member function setStoreId() on boolean

Comment: Yes. Try this code to load the product model:
`$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($subject->getId());`

Comment: worked for me thanks a lot

Comment: @DevelopperMagento You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: i did that but with no result :'(

Comment: that 's what i got in system.logmain.INFO Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and 'header' respectively. [] []
[2019-07-15 10:03:16] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'footer_blog_link' element cannot be added as child to 'footer_links', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-07-15 10:03:16] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'div.sidebar.main' tries to reorder itself towards 'main', but their parents are different: 'div.sidebar' and 'div.col-main' respectively